# Solaris 11 / OpenSolaris - stop processes from listening?

Tags: security, port, tcp, solaris-11

I would like to write a script to secure Solaris 11 servers in preparation for internet access.

In addition to enabling `ipfilter`, I would like to disable network-accessible services that are not used. This should reduce the number of processes shown in `ps`, and also seems cleaner than relying solely on `ipfilter`.

Is there a way I can find out what processes or services are currently listening / responsible for open ports on the server? I would need to filter out those that only listen to `localhost`. I would want to see those that are listening for UDP as well as TCP. If I can get a process ID, or `svcs` name, that would be great!

Once I have a list, I can configure each one as needed, such as restricting `sshd`, disabling `sendmail`, and similar operations for the other services I find on this list.

So how can I get a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the answer body has to be at least 30 symbols, I need to write some stuff here, even the totally dull one, though `netstat -aun` or even `man netstat` would be enough.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know you could get process name from `netstat`. Thanks!

Comment: It's a Solaris 11 new feature. On 10 you would use the shellscript, like it's not 21th century.

Comment: +1. To clarify: What is new in Solaris 11 is the `-u` argument on `netstat`.